# Mysql WHERE column is in string

Tags: php, mysql

I hope, this is not a very stupid question, but since some hours, I'm looking for a solution, but without success.

I have a table with name of cities:

### cities.name

Berlin
New York
Hamburg
...

And I have a string:
"Bonn New York Chicago"

Now, I would like to pick all "known" cities from this string. But as you can see, I'm not able to split this string to an array (because of "New York"). So "FIND_IN_SET" is not suitable for me. The function "LIKE" is working in the "wrong direction".

So I would need something like %cities.name% EKIL $string :-D

Does anyone have an idea, how I can handle this problem without using PHP?

I hope, I'm not missing the forest for the trees...

Thanks a lot for your help!

Tobias

Comment: This is as much a MySQL problem as a PHP one.  Use `WHERE name IN ('Berlin', 'New York', 'Hamburg')`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I think the author does not know yet that the haystack string contains 'Berlin', 'New York' instead of 'Berlin New', 'York Hamburg', etc.

Comment: Foo-Bar on myself.  It helps to read the whole problem.

Comment: @NoChecksum: Yes, you're right. I'm reciving an arbitrary string and I will remove everything other than letters and blanks. So everything could be possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make one `cities` array and then check your string against your cities array.

```
$to_match = array('Bonn','New York','Chicago'); // all cities array

$str = "Bonn New York Chicago"; // Your city string
$new_array = array();

foreach($to_match as $value) {
  if(stristr($str, $value)) {
    $new_array[] = $value;
  }
}

print_r($new_array); // here you can get only match cities against all cities array
```

This will iterate over each `array` element, then check if the value of `match` exists in `$str`, Then it will add it to `$new_array`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It seems, there is no chance to handle it with pure SQL... so, I will take your suggestion. Thanks again for your help!